# JavaCV VideoWriter does not open

Tags: jogl, javacv, video-recording

I want to record a video using JavaCV in JOGL (Java Binding for OpenGL).

This is the code to open the video  file:

```
VideoWriter wv;
wv.open("video.avi", CV_FOURCC_DEFAULT, 30 , new Size(width, height), true);
```

The problem is that wv.isOpened() always returns false and no video file is created.

Things I've tried:

- Change "video.avi" to "video.mp4"
- Change CV_FOURCC_DEFAULT to -1
- Change width, height, fps values

Anyone have achieved this?

My machine is running an Ubuntu 14.04 LTS with JavaCV v1.3.2 and JOGL v2.3.2.

Comment: @aarelovich I'm trying to record what JOGL is drawing in my computer's screen. I get the pixels on each frame with `glReadPixels()`. About the resolution, I've tried both with the resolution of my screen 1920x1080 and the one returned by  `reshape()` which is 1855x1056.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When using OpenCV with C++ I had to define this constant:

```
const int VIDEO_CODEC_FOURCC = CV_FOURCC('M','J','P','G');
```

Try doing using the CV_FOURCC function and the use the .avi file extension as you had originally. Also try to make sure that the camera's frame dimensions are the same as the Size that you passed in your width and height.

Comment: I've used that line but I got: _incompatible types: possible lossy conversion from char to byte_. This can be easily fix by casting. I changed 'CV_FOURCC_DEFAULT' by CV_FOURCC((byte)'M',(byte)'J',(byte)'P',(byte)'G') and now the file is created. Thanks for your help!

Comment: Your are welcome!! I've struggled a lot with this, so, I know how it feels